# Calculating Mode within existing query to count rows in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mode

I have a table `rel` with fields `id` `refid` `cellid` `cat` and some working PHP code to count the number of rows for each `cellid` and return this as an array for later use.

```
<?php
// connect to database
require($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "connect.php");
// count the number of relationships for each cell id
  $cell_array = array();
  if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT cellid, COUNT(*) totalcount, cat FROM rel GROUP BY cellid")) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $cell_array[$row["cellid"]] = $row['totalcount'];
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

I now want to add an additional function, calculate the Mode (most common value) of `cat` for each `cellid` and include that value in the array. If there is more than one mode or no mode then return 9 (`cat` can only have values of 1 to 8).

I've been reading around how to find the Mode and the common solution looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) frequency, cat, cellid
FROM rel
GROUP BY cat
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But this does not return the most common `cat` for each `cellid` just the most common `cat` in general.

I have been working using a sub-query

```
SELECT cellid, cat, COUNT( * ) 
FROM  `rel` 
GROUP BY cellid, cat
```

Which produces a row for each `cellid` `cat` combination, but I'm unsure how to then use this to find the total number of entries for each `cellid` and the the most common `cat` for each `cellid`

**EDIT**

I have made some further progress, I now have a working query to find the mode `cat` for each `cellid`

```
SELECT cellid, cat
FROM rel t
GROUP BY cellid, cat
HAVING cat = ( 
SELECT cat
FROM rel
WHERE cellid = t.cellid
GROUP BY cat
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC , cat
LIMIT 1 )
```

But I am still unsure how to combine the two queries are the output from one cannot be used in the other.

Comment: As better practice, do not `SELECT` columns which are not in your aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them by joining them together:

```
select cell.*, mode.cat as modecat
from (SELECT cellid, COUNT(*) totalcount
      FROM rel
      GROUP BY cellid
     ) cell join
     (SELECT cellid, cat
      FROM rel t
      GROUP BY cellid, cat
      HAVING cat = (SELECT cat
                    FROM rel
                    WHERE cellid = t.cellid
                    GROUP BY cat
                    ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC , cat
                    LIMIT 1
                  )
     ) mode
     on cell.cellid = mode.cnt
```

This doesn't handle the case of multiple values.  If you only wanted an arbitrary value, I would go with:

```
select cell.*,
       (select cat
        from rel
        where cell.cellid = rel.cellid
        group by cellid, cat
        order by COUNT(*) desc
        limit 1
       ) as mode
from (SELECT cellid, COUNT(*) totalcount
      FROM rel
      GROUP BY cellid
     ) cell
```

Identifying muliples is a bit trickier.  It requires an additional aggregation in the subquery:

```
select cell.*,
       (select (case when min(cat) = max(cat) then min(cat) else 'MULTIPLE' end) as mode
        from (select cat, COUNT(*) as cnt
              from rel
              where cell.cellid = rel.cellid
              group by cellid, cat
             ) t
        group by cnt
        order by cnt desc
        limit 1
       ) mode
from (SELECT cellid, COUNT(*) totalcount
      FROM rel
      GROUP BY cellid
     ) cell
```